# How to use Text to Speech (TTS) in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, text-to-speech

I want to make text to speech converter,
I found java have provided free **TTS** (Text to Speech) to do this,
but i don't know how to implement in blackberry.
Please help me to use it.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the free tts you found?   Do you expect to run the tts directly on the blackberry, or will you implement your own  tts code based on the free one?

Comment: http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php#download_and_install

Answer (score 0):

From the freetts faq, the code requires JDK 1.4, so is using features that aren't available on the blackberry device java API:

[Why must I use Java 2 SDK, Standard Edition, v1.4?](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php#why_jdk1.4)

> Some of the many compelling reasons to use Java 2 SDK, Standard
>   Edition, v1.4. are:
>
> New IO package - Java 2 SDK, Standard Edition, v1.4 provides a new IO
>   (java.nio) package that provides memory mapped file I/O. This package
>   drastically reduces the load times of the FreeTTS databases.   Regular
>   expressions - Java 2 SDK, Standard Edition, v1.4 provides a new
>   package for regular expression matching (java.util.regex). They are
>   used in the FreeTTS text normalization step.   Assert Facility - Java
>   2 SDK, Standard Edition, v1.4 added the new assert keyword to ensure
>   that certain conditions are satisfied before continuing execution.
>   FreeTTS uses this keyword in all stages of speech synthesis.
>   Compiler Optimizations - Java 2 SDK, Standard Edition, v1.4 has
>   numerous compiler optimizations that produce faster and more compact
>   code. For example, with the -server switch, byte codes are optimized
>   to eliminate bounds checking on array accesses whenever possible.